# Kickstart installed nothing?

Tags: installation, commerce

I followed the install directions by deleting all but the /sites folder, copied the files into the drupal dir, deleted the cache but nothing changed except and notice that drupal core needed updating to 7.24, which i did.  What am i missing here?

Answer (score 0):

By considering that you have gone through pre-installation checklist of Commerce Kickstart, following are the steps to install commerce kickstart :

1. Download Commerce Kickstart.
2. Extract the Files into root directory.
3. Installation Screen, welcome.
4. Requirements Problem Screen.
5. Setting up the database configuration.
6. Installation running through.
7. Site Configuration.
8. Configure Store Content.
9. Importing Products.